# How to pass long data to mySql database at freemysqlhosting.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I am using freemysqlhosting.net to host my database and I am doing actions by using their library :

```
var MySql = {
    _internalCallback : function() { console.log("Callback not set")},
    Execute: function ( Sql, Callback) 
    {
      MySql._internalCallback = Callback;
      Host = "sql9.freemysqlhosting.net";
      Username = "myUserName";
      Password = "MyPassword";
      Database = "MyDatabase";

      var strSrc = "http://mysqljs.com/sql.aspx?";
      strSrc += "Host=" + Host;
      strSrc += "&Username=" + Username;
      strSrc += "&Password=" + Password;
      strSrc += "&Database=" + Database;
      strSrc += "&sql=" + Sql;
      strSrc += "&Callback=MySql._internalCallback";
      alert(strSrc);
      console.log('rabee: '+ strSrc);
      var sqlScript = document.createElement('script');
      sqlScript.setAttribute('src', strSrc);
      document.head.appendChild(sqlScript);
    }
};
```

Then if I want to insert data into table inside this database, I do it simply by doing this:

```
 var command = 
 "INSERT INTO myTable(id,name,email,data) VALUES ('2','rabee','test@test.com','anydata')";

 MySql.Execute(command,function(data){
                              showAllRaws();
                              alert(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
                              });
```

When I insert short data inside the data column I got a successful callback, but when I insert long data nothing happens and no callback.

My questions are :
1- Is there any limitation for long URL request or am I doing something wrong?
2- How to replace their tiny library with AJAX request?

Comment: Could you please use die(mysql_error()) in your insert statement while passing long value and check what error if there exists it will show.

Comment: I think it is a server issue, I was able to insert data via URL from the browser, but if the inserted URL more than 2075 characters I get a server error:

Answer (score -1):

Please check your datatype in the database and whether you are using use "text" datatype it will accept all data.